# Reduce Size of .apk file

Tags: android

I want to reduce the size of my android application, so I started exploring what is there in my apps .apk file, strange I want images from hololighttheme in the resources folder, although I selected none in themes while creating my project in eclipse. Can anyone help to prevent these default images creeping into my application?

Comment: `strange I wanted images from hololighttheme in the resources folder, although I selected none in themes while creating my project in eclipse.` can you explain more about you problem here??

Comment: When I unzipped my .apk file, there in resource folder it contained images like abc_ab_bottom_solid_light_holo.9.png in drawable-hdpi,drawable-mdpi,drawable-xhdpi,drawable-xxhdpi, which are of no use to me and I want to remove them

Comment: is these images are there when you build your apk?

Comment: no before i build my apk these images are not there in resources folder, even after i build , in the bin\res\crunch these images are not there, but these are included in the .apk file

Comment: first of all debug the app and find from where the files are coming and try to delete it

Comment: May be, You have dependencies on other projects and resources are from that library project.

Comment: it is very basic helloworld project, with no dependencies on any other project, only jar included in it is of android.jar

Comment: Adhikari Bishwash, you were correct , as I had dependency on library project, which I forgot to remove, I was removing the jars from android dependencies but I had referenced library project via Properties->Android->Reference. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not keeping unnecessary images in drawable folders. The APK file is basically a .zip file, so there’s no way of compressing its size any further.

I can give you following tips which will help you reduce the size of APK file.

Use [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) to obfuscate the code,which will not only will provide you security but also it will shrink the code to great extent.

Switch off all debug logs when you are releasing app in production.

```
static final boolean debug = false;
if (debug) {
Log.v(TAG,"blah blah blah");
}
```

Use a tool such as [OptiPNG](http://optipng.sourceforge.net/) or [PNGCrush](http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/) reducing PNG file size while still ensuring image quality.

Comment: My problem is that I dont know from where are these images coming into my zipped .apk file, I dont have these images in resource folder of my project