# Size of .apk android

Tags: android, apk

After building apk file, I noticed my application size is 2MB(Raw file size) &  1.7MB(Download Size). But the application is very simple which as size of <500kb (includes resource and java files) where the **classes.dex** alone is taking around 1.3MB as [image: here].

I have used the **ProGuard** to obfuscate the code as below

```
android {
...

buildTypes {
    release {
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
        'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

I also have been through the links [Reduce Size of .apk file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23820952/reduce-size-of-apk-file)
 and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29151530/reducing-size-of-apk-through-libraries) on stack overflow but not find what as to be done to reduce the .apk size.

the only dependency added in **gradle** is:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
```

}

I am pretty sure this is due to support library add-in. So can some one help me finding the way to reduce/minimise this size?

Any insight is greatly appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: add `shrinkResources true`

Comment: Thanks for your response@Amiya ,that also used but forgot to put the line in the code. As I mentioned the classes.dex is taking more space so do you know any other way to reduce app size?

Answer (score 0):

Read [**`Shrink Your Code and Resources`**](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html)

> Resource shrinking works only in conjunction with code shrinking.
>   After the code shrinker removes all unused code, the resource shrinker
>   can identify which resources the app still uses. This is especially
>   true when you add code libraries that include resources—you must
>   remove unused library code so the library resources become
>   unreferenced and, thus, removable by the resource shrinker.

To enable resource shrinking, set the **`shrinkResources`** property to true in your **`build.gradle`** file (alongside minifyEnabled for code shrinking). For example:

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            zipAlignEnabled true <-- optimization
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

**FYI**

You can use [**`VECTOR`**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources.html) images.Using vector drawables instead of several bitmaps reduces the size of your apk.

> classes.dex: All Java source files are converted to Java class files
>   by the Java compiler. The Android SDK contains a tool called dx which
>   converts Java class files into a .dex (Dalvik Executable) file.

Comment: check my edited code I have used that . The size mentioned in here is after using "shrinkResources true"

Comment: @Shree Use Vector(SVG) images.

Comment: @Amiya The attached image clearly signifies the classes.dex is taking more size. No issue with added images in drawable. As I have very less no of images that too all image sizes are in some bytes. Any other way?

Comment: @Shree Any feedback? Did you reduce size?

Comment: No, the size remains same. But I found the solution, the reason for large .apk  is support library dependency. Anyways thanks for your response. The blog you mentioned is very informative.